# ¿Por qué _name es igual a name?

Tags: javascript, clase

Estoy aprendiendo la sintaxis básica de clases en Javascript y me ha surgido una duda importante. Usando el constructor pretendo crear y darle valor a la propiedad `this.name`, mientras que usando los getters y setters pretendo obtener y modificar `this._name` suponiendo que _name es una propiedad 'interna' del objeto y por lo tanto no debería poder modificarse sin el uso del set. Lo que no logro comprender es lo siguiente:

```js
"use strict";

class Admin {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    };

    get name() {
        return this._name;
    };

    set name(value) {
        if (value.length < 4) {
            console.log('Nombre demasiado corto!');
            return;
        };
        this._name = value
    };
};

let admin = new Admin('Julio');

//Por qué _name === name si todavía no he ejecutado el set?
//_name no debería existir, debería ser undefined

console.log(admin._name);
console.log(admin.name);
console.log(admin);

admin.name = 'Roberto';

//Por qué _name === name si el set no afecta a name, sino a _name?
//admin.name debería ser 'Julio' y admin.name 'Roberto'

console.log(admin._name);
console.log(admin.name);
console.log(admin);

//otra duda que tengo es porqué al mandar admin a consola, se muestra _name pero no name dentro del objeto
```

Como pueden ver, mi principal duda es con respecto al set y el constructor, quienes agregan _name aunque yo no haya ejecutado el set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos a analizar las asignaciones paso a paso y cómo se recorren dentro de la función y el porque:

Después de definir la función ejecutas esto:

```javascript
let admin = new Admin('Julio');
```

Lo cual primero pasa por el constructor:

```javascript
class Admin {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    };
```

Hasta ahí todo correcto, si la clase no tuviera más métodos podriamos acceder a la propiedad de la clase mediante:

```javascript
console.log(admin.name)
```

Pero ocurre que tenemos otro método que afecta a lo que acaba de suceder, que es el **set**, que pones a más abajo:

```javascript
    set name(value) {
        if (value.length < 4) {
            console.log('Nombre demasiado corto!');
            return;
        };
        this._name = value
    };
```

¿Y porqué afecta? Pues si nos vamos a [este enlace](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set), verás que dicen lo siguiente:

> La sintaxis  set  asocia la propiedad de un objeto a una función que
> será llamada cuando haya un intento de asignar valor a esa propiedad.

Quedémonos con esta frase: **una función que será llamada cuando haya un intento de asignar valor a esa propiedad**.

Es decir, el **set** actua también porque ¿dentro del constructor que hemos hecho?  Pues eso, hemos intentado asignar valor a esa propiedad `name` mediante el `this.name = name`, lo cual ha disparado la función `set`.

¿Y que hace **set**?  Pues al final de la función realiza esto:

```javascript
        this._name = value
```

Es decir, acaba de crear una nueva propiedad `_name` con el mismo valor de la asignación que hemos visto en el contructor, porque lo que vemos en el paréntesis como parámetro `value` viene a ser equivalente a lo asignado mediante `this.name=`, es decir, el parámetro `name` del constructor.

Hasta aquí la primera pregunta: `¿Por qué _name === name si todavía no he ejecutado el set?` y la respuesta corta seria: **Sí, has  ejecutado el `set` al asignarle un valor a la propiedad `name` en el constructor**.

Ahora vamos con la segunda pregunta: **`¿Por qué _name === name si el set no afecta a name, sino a _name?`**

Bueno, si repasas el código que has puesto de ejemplo al asignar `Roberto`, verás tu confusión. Fíjate bien en la línea de la asignación:

```javascript
admin.name = 'Roberto';
```

Así, a salto de mata, sin pensar que hay una clase detrás, ¿que ves?  Yo veo una asignación a la propiedad `name` de un objeto denominado `admin`. Luego resulta que es una instancia de una clase, vale, pues entonces deduzco que viene a ser lo mismo pero para una instancia de clase, es decir, **una asignación a la propiedad `name` de una instancia de clase representada por el objeto `admin`**.  Del mismo modo que antes, sin saber que más hace la clase, ni si tiene setters y getters, si ahora hicieramos esto:

```javascript
console.log(admin.name)
```

nos devolveria `Roberto`.
Pero resulta que sí que tiene un `set name` establecido, por lo tanto tiene que ejecutarse por la misma definición dada antes:

> La sintaxis  set  asocia la propiedad de un objeto a una función que
> será llamada cuando haya un intento de asignar valor a esa propiedad.

Y voilà, vuelve a suceder exactamente lo mismo que he explicado antes, y se le asigna el valor a `_name` establecido a `name`, pues así lo dice el `set` al final:

```javascript
        this._name = value
```

Y así queda respondida también tu segunda duda: **`¿Por qué _name === name si el set no afecta a name, sino a _name?`** , que brevemente la respuesta seria:  **¡Tienes razón! El set no afecta a `name`, pero es que es `admin.name=` quien afecta al `set name` y lo dispara causando esta segunda equivalencia de valores entre `name` y `_name`**.

No se si ahora lo ves o no, yo lo he puesto como lo entiendo y me cuadra :-)

Ya nos diras si ahora tu también compartes este planteamiento.

Comment: Vale, entiendo casi todo, me queda solo una duda. la asignación this.name = name dentro del constructor hace que se ejecute el set de name(), correcto? dentro del set se hace la asignación de this._name = value, por lo que suponiendo que value = 'Julio' entonces this._name === 'Julio'; Ahora, el set, como ya lo citaste, es una función que será llamada cuando haya un intento de asignar valor a esa propiedad. Al terminar de ejecutar el set, no retorna nada, por lo que: ¿No se supone que this.name debería ser igual a undefined? o sea this.name === undefined, ya que set name() no retorna nada.

Comment: Dos preguntas, dos respuestas: 1ra) Sí, es correcto, la respuesta breve a todo lo que planteas es **El `set name(value)` se ejecuta automáticamente al asignar un valor a la propiedad `name`, sea como sea, desde dentro o desde fuera de la clase**.  Y 2da) Si se ejecuta el **set name(value)** es porque hay alguna asignación a la propiedad `name` en alguna parte, por lo tanto se va a producir la asignacion **previa** al `set name(value)` y luego lo que contenga ese método **set**. Ahora, si le pasas un `value` de `undefined` entiendo que se quedará con el ¿Se me entiende así?

Comment: @AndrésArrieche Y eso que dices que no retorna nada es normal, pues queda asignado en la instancia de la clase en el objeto `admin` que has establecido, aunque si quieres que retorne algo tan solo debes ponerle un `return loquequierasretornar` al final de la función, pero no tendria demasiado sentido en este contexto.  (Te aconsejo que no me leas literalmente ni analices mis palabras una a una, pues me puedo equivocar en las expresiones y hacerte un lio con ellas. Intenta más bien pillar la idea y conceptos de lo que digo y abstraerlo todo para que tenga lógica para ti)

Comment: @AndrésArrieche Digo esto de las expresiones literales porque los comentarios a veces son escritos demasiado rápido y puedo equivocarme, y una vez pasados 5 minutos ya no podré repasarlos más y pueden quedar mal descritos para siempre a pesar que haya visto los errores (pues no podré modificarlos, solo borrarlos pero se perderia contexto y el hilo de lo que vamos diciendo)

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente, para saber por qué hace referencia a _name, hay que entender para qué se utiliza la barrabaja ( _ ) en JavaScript:

> El signo dólar ($) y barrabaja (_) son identificadores JavaScript, lo
> cual significa que identifican un objeto de la misma forma que haría
> un nombre. Los objetos que identifica incluyen variables, funciones,
> propiedades, eventos y objetos. La barrabaja es utilizada normalmente en programación para hacer referencia a métodos y variables **privados**.

Por tanto, significa que no deberías usar estos métodos (que empiezan por "_") fuera de tu objeto. Técnicamente puedes, pero " _ " significa que no deberías. Hará referencia a la variable, función, método, etc. que tenga el mismo nombre con el que lo creaste.

Comment: Entiendo que no es recomendable usar propiedades 'privadas'(con barrabaja) fuera del objeto. Pero la cuestión es que, según lo que entiendo, _name y name deberían tener contenidos distintos, cosa que no sucede

Comment: Claro, deberian tener contenidos distintos si se hiciera referencia a algo fuera del objeto; al llamar al objeto desde fuera con los console.log(admin.name) y console.log(admin._name), el valor que envías al objeto es el mismo (Entiende como si le enviaras 2 veces admin.name), y entiende que haces referencia a lo mismo, por eso el console.log te devuelve el mismo nombre

Comment: No creo que ses sea el caso, porque probé lo siguiente: let obj = {}; obj.name = 'Francisco'; obj._name = 'Bernardo'; console.log(obj.name); console.log(obj._name); Y me muestran Francisco y Bernardo respectivamente

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta @DarklceDust no esta mal, pero no es la razon por la que tu codigo se comporta de esta manera.
Tu *getter* y *setter* se llaman igual que tu propiedad: *name*. De alguna manera javascript (tratare de buscar alguna fuente/documentacion donde respalde esto) crea una propiedad `_name` esto para evitar una recursion infinita.

Al tener esto:

```javascript
class Admin {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    };

    get name() {
        return this.name;
    };

    set name(value) {
        if (value.length < 4) {
            console.log('Nombre demasiado corto!');
            return;
        };
        this.name = value
    };
};

const admin = new Admin('Julio')
```

Si hace esto: `admin.name` estaria llamando al *getter* name que a su vez ejecuta `return this.name` esto estaria llamando al mismo *getter* otra vez y asi hasta el infinito.
Algunos IDE's o editores de texto como vscode arrojan un error al tener el codigo como en el ejemplo de arriba.
La convencion es que en el metodo *get* y *set* uses la barra baja para referirte a la propiedad y no al metodo *get* o *set*.

```javascript
class Admin {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    };

    get name() {
        return this._name;
    };

    set name(value) {
        if (value.length < 4) {
            console.log('Nombre demasiado corto!');
            return;
        };
        this._name = value
    };
};

const admin = new Admin('Julio')

// imprime 'Julio'
// se ejecuta el metodo get que se llama 'name'
console.log(admin.name)

// Imporime 'Julio'
// JS crea esta propiedad al crear la instancia
console.log(admin._name)
```

De hecho a lo metodos get y set los puedes nombrar diferente a la propiedad y asi evitar la barra baja:

```javascript
class Admin {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    };

    get otraCosa() {
        return this.name;
    };

    set otraCosa(value) {
        if (value.length < 4) {
            console.log('Nombre demasiado corto!');
            return;
        };
        this.name = value
    };
};

const admin = new Admin('Julio')

// Imprime 'Julio'
// ya que el metodo get se llama 'otraCosa' y este
// retorna el valor de 'name'
cosole.log(admin.otraCosa) 

// Imprime 'Julio'
// ya que la propiedad asi se llama
console.log(admin.name)
```